# How to find/replace standalone words or words with certain adjectives?

Tags: python, regex

> German apple is good. Apple is nice. Where is the apple? English apple
>   have worms. English people are nice.

If I have an example as above, I would like to replace all occurrences of `Apple` or `apple` with `German apple`. In the example above `German apple` should be ignored as it is already correct. Only one exception, if there is `English apple` then it should still be replaced to `German apple`

Using online [regex generators](http://www.regexr.com/), I came up with this:

It seems the following allows me to select all apples (globally, multilines)
But this also selects the `German apple`, which I should disallow.

```
/\b(apple)/igm
```

This attempt doesn't really work either. It only selects `apple?`.

```
/\b(apple)[^German apple]/igm
```

I am stuck here already. Would be grateful for a hint.

**UPDATE**:

I am looking at positive and negative lookaround as explained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

If I had another line added to the above example:

> Apple from Dutch is sour.

And I want to say ignore `Apple from Dutch` as we did with `German apple`. 
How can this be achieved?

I tried this without luck:

```
(?i)(?:English )?(?:(?<!German )\bapple\b(?<! from dutch))
```

Comment: So what should happen to `Dutch apple`, or `rotten apple`? What about `products produced by Apple`?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you brought up good points. The latter won't be an issue in my example. `Dutch` and `rotten` apple are treated like standalone apple. It shall be replaced nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with `German apple`

```
(?<!German )(?:English )?\bapple\b
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/17)

OR

```
(?i)(?:English )?(?:(?<!German )\bapple\b)
```

- `(?i)` Case insensitive modifier.
- `(?:English )?` Matches the optional `English` strings.
- `(?:(?<!German )\bapple\b)` Matches all the `apple` strings only if it's not preceded by `German` . `(?<!German )` negative lookbehind asserts that the string we are going to match won't be preceded by the string which was matched by the pattern present inside the negative lookbehind.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/18)

Example:

```
>>> string = 'German apple is good. Apple is nice. Where is the apple? English apple have worms. English people are nice.'
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)(?:English )?(?:(?<!German )\bapple\b)', r'German apple', string)
'German apple is good. German apple is nice. Where is the German apple? German apple have worms. English people are nice.'
```

**Update:**

```
(?i)(?:English )?(?:(?<!German )\bapple\b)(?!\s+from\s+Dutch\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gN4sX6/3)

Comment: That works. Many thanks. Would you kindly explain your code a bit. So I understand it better?

Comment: Your example was really helpful. If I had one more sentence like this: `apple from Dutch is sour.` How can I look ahead and exclude this as well as you did with `German apple` ?

Comment: what i need to do with the above? What's the expected output?